# Assign JSON to value in input

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', function(data) {
      $('.myip').text(data.ip);
    });
  };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org/?format=json"></script>

<script>
  $('.send').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/' + $('.ip').val() + '/json', function(data) {
      $('.city').text(data.city);
      $('.country_name').text(data.country_name);
      $('.country_code').text(data.country_code);
      $('.region').text(data.region);
      $('.region_code').text(data.region_code);
      $('.postal').text(data.postal);
      $('.timezone').text(data.timezone);
      $('.latitude').text(data.latitude);
      $('.longitude').text(data.longitude);
      $('.ip').text(data.ip);
      $('.org').text(data.org);
      $('.asn').text(data.asn);
    });
  });
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="ip" id="ip" maxlength="15" class="ipnput ip" value="">
<button type="button" class="submit send" id="showDiv" value="Check">Check</button>
```

In the javascript portion, I'm using ipify to grab the visiting users IP. I'd like to attach it to the html input value on load while running the second part of the JS that makes a call to ipapi with that ipify ip. New to JS so hoping someone could steer me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: the given code has syntax errors, remove that.

Comment: Did you simply confuse `$('.myip')` and `$('.ip')`? The former is updated with the IP address from ipify, but the latter is subsequently used in the call to ipapi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it pretty much right, but errors come from the typo.

In the `onload` handler you are targeting `$('.myip')` when in the HMTL you don't have an input with such classs. Also you need to use `.val` jQuery method.

Also the script element with `ipify.org` call in `src` is extra, not needed.

Try this:

```
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json', function(data) {
      $('.ip').val(data.ip);
    });
  };
</script>

<script>
  $('.send').on('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
    $.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/' + $('.ip').val() + '/json', function(data) {
      $('.city').text(data.city);
      $('.country_name').text(data.country_name);
      $('.country_code').text(data.country_code);
      $('.region').text(data.region);
      $('.region_code').text(data.region_code);
      $('.postal').text(data.postal);
      $('.timezone').text(data.timezone);
      $('.latitude').text(data.latitude);
      $('.longitude').text(data.longitude);
      $('.ip').text(data.ip);
      $('.org').text(data.org);
      $('.asn').text(data.asn);
    });
  });
</script>
```